# mangle and raw table, which is processed first?

Tags: iptables

I checked `iptables (8)`, but it doesn't tell me the order between raw table and mangle table, I only know raw is proceed before nat and filter.

Answer (score 0):

I think its PREROUTING Chain of **raw>mangle**